# Is there something like a sleep mode in pocketsphinx android?

Tags: android, pocketsphinx-android

I'm building a sample project with Pocketsphinx4Android (the Android Studio version).

I'm using an own language model and i have good results but it completly stops my ui if it receives no "speech input" for a while.

Does anybody know if there's something like a automatic sleep mode for pocketsphinx?

My App doesn't crash completly, only the ui gets blocked (sometimes > 1 min), the debug point gets also hit after this delay and I'm able to proceed.

Thank you.

update: logcat ouput.

//output at application startup, keyword is recognized fine (21:53 MEZ)

```
04-02 21:53:17.610  11737-12074/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(302): Utterance vocabulary contains 0 words
04-02 21:53:17.620  11737-11737/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/SpeechRecognizer﹕ Stop recognition
04-02 21:53:17.620  11737-11737/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto E/cmusphinx﹕ ERROR: "ngram_search.c", line 1141: Couldn't find <s> in first frame
04-02 21:53:17.620  11737-11737/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/SpeechRecognizer﹕ Start recognition "wakeup"
04-02 21:53:17.630     151-4838/? I/audio_policy_mrvl﹕ get_device_for_input_source: Input source 6, device 80000004
04-02 21:53:17.630     151-4838/? I/wrap_samsungREC﹕ [wrap_samsungREC] CreateSamsungREC init
04-02 21:53:17.630     151-4838/? I/samsungRecord﹕ [samsungrecord] SamsungRecInit
04-02 21:53:17.640     151-4838/? I/samsungRecord﹕ [samsungrecordMIC]Use HardCoding Values
04-02 21:53:17.640     151-4838/? I/samsungRecord﹕ 1
04-02 21:53:17.640     151-4838/? I/audio_hw_mrvl﹕ mrvl_hw_dev_open_input_stream: in->device 80000000, in->sample_rate 44100
04-02 21:53:17.670  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: pocketsphinx.c(863): Writing raw audio log file: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto/files/sync/000000006.raw
04-02 21:53:17.670     151-4838/? I/audio_policy_mrvl﹕ mrvl_ap_dev_start_input: input 760
04-02 21:53:17.670      151-352/? I/AudioSystem﹕ AudioSystem::setParameters(STREAM_IN_ACTIVE=1;routing=-2147483644;voice_recognition=on)
04-02 21:53:17.680    151-12078/? I/audio_hw_mrvl﹕ stream_in_set: buffer_time_max is 116100, buffer_time_min is 11609, requested is 100000
04-02 21:53:17.680    151-12078/? I/audio_hw_mrvl﹕ stream_in_set: period time eventually set as 20000 usec
04-02 21:53:17.680    151-12078/? I/audio_hw_mrvl﹕ stream_in_set: buffer time eventually set as 100000 usec
04-02 21:53:17.680    151-12078/? I/audio_hw_mrvl﹕ stream_in_set: bufferSize is 4410, periodSize is 882
04-02 21:53:17.680    151-12078/? I/MarvellAmixer﹕ get_amixer_value, device 80000004, left volume 125, right volume 125, codec info 0, mic mode 2
04-02 21:53:17.680    151-12078/? I/AudioHIFIPath﹕ default_enable: Enable hifi input device earpiece
04-02 21:53:17.680    151-12078/? I/acm_aph﹕ ACM_APHPathHandling: path=HiFiRecognitionRecordFromMic2 operation=ENABLE ref_path=(null) amixer value=0x20460064
04-02 21:53:17.680    151-12078/? I/acm_aph﹕ ACM_APHPathHandling: Current active path count=1
04-02 21:53:17.680    151-12078/? I/acm_ach_elba﹕ Elba_Enable: enable elba component
04-02 21:53:19.182  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: cmn_prior.c(99): cmn_prior_update: from <
04-02 21:53:19.182  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 31.92
04-02 21:53:19.182  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -10.33
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 3.02
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -3.70
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -2.30
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -4.98
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 0.76
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 0.06
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -0.17
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 0.81
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -0.52
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -0.09
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -0.95
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ >
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: cmn_prior.c(116): cmn_prior_update: to   <
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 31.70
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -10.55
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 2.65
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -4.03
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -2.45
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -4.64
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 0.99
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 0.43
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 0.21
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 0.78
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -0.61
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 0.05
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -0.72
04-02 21:53:19.192  11737-12077/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ >
```

I left the device in an absolute quiet
after half an hour I made the keyword test again.

```
//KEYWORD SPOKEN
    04-02 22:32:31.897      151-384/? I/audio_policy_mrvl﹕ mrvl_ap_dev_stop_input: input 827
    04-02 22:32:31.897      151-352/? I/AudioSystem﹕ AudioSystem::setParameters(STREAM_IN_ACTIVE=0;routing=-2147483648;voice_recognition=off)
    04-02 22:32:31.907    151-12274/? I/MarvellAmixer﹕ get_amixer_value, device 80000004, left volume 0, right volume 0, codec info 0, mic mode 2
    04-02 22:32:31.907    151-12274/? I/AudioHIFIPath﹕ default_disable: Disable hifi input device earpiece
    04-02 22:32:31.907    151-12274/? I/acm_aph﹕ ACM_APHPathHandling: path=HiFiRecognitionRecordFromMic2 operation=DISABLE ref_path=(null) amixer value=0x0
    04-02 22:32:31.907    151-12274/? I/acm_aph﹕ ACM_APHPathHandling: Current active path count=0
    04-02 22:32:31.917    151-12274/? I/acm_ach_elba﹕ Elba_Disable: disable elba component
    04-02 22:32:31.927     151-4838/? I/audio_policy_mrvl﹕ mrvl_ap_dev_release_input: 827
    04-02 22:32:31.937  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: cmn_prior.c(131): cmn_prior_update: from <
    04-02 22:32:31.937  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 39.57
    04-02 22:32:31.937  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -17.53
    04-02 22:32:31.937  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 7.55
    04-02 22:32:31.937  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -10.15
    04-02 22:32:31.937  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 2.16
    04-02 22:32:31.937  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -2.96
    04-02 22:32:31.937  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -1.95
    04-02 22:32:31.937  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 0.43
    04-02 22:32:31.937  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -4.66
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 0.50
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -1.83
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 0.72
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -2.44
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ >
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: cmn_prior.c(149): cmn_prior_update: to   <
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 39.70
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -14.30
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 8.83
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -8.17
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 2.15
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -3.39
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -0.90
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -0.78
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -4.60
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 0.54
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -1.44
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 0.31
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -3.37
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ >
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1550):    36062 words recognized (8/fr)
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1552):   703409 senones evaluated (157/fr)
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1556):   261258 channels searched (58/fr), 66750 1st, 62417 last
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1559):    36860 words for which last channels evaluated (8/fr)
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1561):    13937 candidate words for entering last phone (3/fr)
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1564): fwdtree 25.92 CPU 0.580 xRT
    04-02 22:32:31.947  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1567): fwdtree 232.21 wall 5.194 xRT
    04-02 22:32:31.977  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(302): Utterance vocabulary contains 6 words
    04-02 22:32:32.848  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(938):    30958 words recognized (7/fr)
    04-02 22:32:32.848  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(940):   166036 senones evaluated (37/fr)
    04-02 22:32:32.848  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(942):    60973 channels searched (13/fr)
    04-02 22:32:32.848  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(944):    32515 words searched (7/fr)
    04-02 22:32:32.848  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(947):      696 word transitions (0/fr)
    04-02 22:32:32.848  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(950): fwdflat 0.90 CPU 0.020 xRT
    04-02 22:32:32.848  11737-12273/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(953): fwdflat 0.90 wall 0.020 xRT
    04-02 22:32:32.848  11737-11737/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/SpeechRecognizer﹕ Stop recognition
    04-02 22:32:33.499      579-871/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 1004


//APP UI IS BLOCKED NOW, I JUST GET TOUCH EVENTS
    04-02 22:32:37.322      579-705/? I/InputReader﹕ Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.272 ] when=30139388519000
    04-02 22:32:37.322      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Delivering touch to: action: 0x0, toolType: 1
    04-02 22:32:37.432      579-705/? I/InputReader﹕ Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] when=30139498107000
    04-02 22:32:37.432      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Delivering touch to: action: 0x1, toolType: 1
    04-02 22:32:38.033      579-705/? I/InputReader﹕ Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.273 ] when=30140093078000
    04-02 22:32:38.173  11737-11737/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: ngram_search.c(1199): </s> not found in last frame, using OPEN.4469 instead
    04-02 22:32:38.173  11737-11737/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: ngram_search.c(1252): lattice start node <s>.0 end node OPEN.4423
    04-02 22:32:38.173  11737-11737/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: ngram_search.c(1278): Eliminated 93 nodes before end node
    04-02 22:32:38.183      579-705/? I/InputReader﹕ Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] when=30140247589000
    04-02 22:32:38.684      579-705/? I/InputReader﹕ Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.274 ] when=30140749023000
    04-02 22:32:38.814      579-705/? I/InputReader﹕ Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] when=30140872863000
    04-02 22:32:39.354      579-705/? I/InputReader﹕ Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.275 ] when=30141412261000
    04-02 22:32:39.484      579-705/? I/InputReader﹕ Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] when=30141543762000
    04-02 22:32:39.705      579-705/? I/InputReader﹕ Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.276 ] when=30141769012000
    04-02 22:32:39.845      579-705/? I/InputReader﹕ Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] when=30141900268000
    04-02 22:32:39.995      579-705/? I/InputReader﹕ Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.277 ] when=30142051971000
    04-02 22:32:40.095      579-705/? I/InputReader﹕ Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] when=30142150177000
    04-02 22:32:40.195      579-705/? I/InputReader﹕ Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.278 ] when=30142259216000
    04-02 22:32:40.275      579-705/? I/InputReader﹕ Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] when=30142332763000
    04-02 22:32:40.395      579-705/? I/InputReader﹕ Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.279 ] when=30142452972000
    04-02 22:32:40.475      579-705/? I/InputReader﹕ Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] when=30142535034000
    04-02 22:32:42.117      579-705/? I/InputReader﹕ Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.280 ] when=30144175903000
    04-02 22:32:42.237      579-705/? I/InputReader﹕ Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] when=30144297454000
    04-02 22:32:49.494    1696-1696/? I/wpa_supplicant﹕ wlan0: Setting scan request: 0 sec 0 usec
    04-02 22:32:49.494    1696-1696/? I/wpa_supplicant﹕ Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds
    04-02 22:32:53.008    1696-1696/? I/wpa_supplicant﹕ nl80211: Received scan results (5 BSSes)
    04-02 22:32:58.052      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Application is not responding. It has been 20017.2ms since event, 20016.6ms since wait started.  Reason: Waiting because the touched window has not finished processing the input events that were previously delivered to it.
    04-02 22:32:58.052      579-704/? I/WindowManager﹕ Input event dispatching timed out sending to rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto.RBGUIAndroidActivity.  Reason: Waiting because the touched window has not finished processing the input events that were previously delivered to it.
    04-02 22:33:03.498      579-871/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 1005
    04-02 22:33:03.508      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:03.508      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.053  11737-11737/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: ngram_search.c(1383): Lattice has 19204 nodes, 127512 links
    04-02 22:33:09.414  11737-11737/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: ps_lattice.c(1368): Normalizer P(O) = alpha(OPEN:4423:4469) = -27073656
    04-02 22:33:09.534  11737-11737/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: ps_lattice.c(1403): Joint P(O,S) = -27073732 P(S|O) = -76
    04-02 22:33:09.534  11737-11737/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: ngram_search.c(874): bestpath 36.40 CPU 0.814 xRT
    04-02 22:33:09.534  11737-11737/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: ngram_search.c(877): bestpath 36.69 wall 0.821 xRT
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Window spent 32207.7ms processing the last input event:
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Window spent 32172.4ms processing the last input event:
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Window spent 32160.8ms processing the last input event:
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Window spent 32148.7ms processing the last input event:
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Window spent 32136.5ms processing the last input event:
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Window spent 32124.5ms processing the last input event:
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Window spent 32112.2ms processing the last input event:
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.534      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropped event because it is stale.
    04-02 22:33:09.544      579-704/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Window spent 32102.4ms

//keyword is recognized now (i have a textview for that in my view) and UI isn't
//blocking anymore.

 processing the last input event:
    04-02 22:33:09.544  11737-11737/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/SpeechRecognizer﹕ Start recognition "wakeup"
    04-02 22:33:09.544      151-384/? I/audio_policy_mrvl﹕ get_device_for_input_source: Input source 6, device 80000004
    04-02 22:33:09.544      151-384/? I/wrap_samsungREC﹕ [wrap_samsungREC] CreateSamsungREC init
    04-02 22:33:09.544      151-384/? I/samsungRecord﹕ [samsungrecord] SamsungRecInit
    04-02 22:33:09.544      151-384/? I/samsungRecord﹕ [samsungrecordMIC]Use HardCoding Values
    04-02 22:33:09.544      151-384/? I/samsungRecord﹕ 1
    04-02 22:33:09.544      151-384/? I/audio_hw_mrvl﹕ mrvl_hw_dev_open_input_stream: in->device 80000000, in->sample_rate 44100
    04-02 22:33:09.574  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: pocketsphinx.c(863): Writing raw audio log file: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto/files/sync/000000039.raw
    04-02 22:33:09.574      151-384/? I/audio_policy_mrvl﹕ mrvl_ap_dev_start_input: input 829
    04-02 22:33:09.574      151-352/? I/AudioSystem﹕ AudioSystem::setParameters(STREAM_IN_ACTIVE=1;routing=-2147483644;voice_recognition=on)
    04-02 22:33:09.584    151-12288/? I/audio_hw_mrvl﹕ stream_in_set: buffer_time_max is 116100, buffer_time_min is 11609, requested is 100000
    04-02 22:33:09.584    151-12288/? I/audio_hw_mrvl﹕ stream_in_set: period time eventually set as 20000 usec
    04-02 22:33:09.584    151-12288/? I/audio_hw_mrvl﹕ stream_in_set: buffer time eventually set as 100000 usec
    04-02 22:33:09.584    151-12288/? I/audio_hw_mrvl﹕ stream_in_set: bufferSize is 4410, periodSize is 882
    04-02 22:33:09.584    151-12288/? I/MarvellAmixer﹕ get_amixer_value, device 80000004, left volume 125, right volume 125, codec info 0, mic mode 2
    04-02 22:33:09.584    151-12288/? I/AudioHIFIPath﹕ default_enable: Enable hifi input device earpiece
    04-02 22:33:09.584    151-12288/? I/acm_aph﹕ ACM_APHPathHandling: path=HiFiRecognitionRecordFromMic2 operation=ENABLE ref_path=(null) amixer value=0x20460064
    04-02 22:33:09.584    151-12288/? I/acm_aph﹕ ACM_APHPathHandling: Current active path count=1
    04-02 22:33:09.584    151-12288/? I/acm_ach_elba﹕ Elba_Enable: enable elba component
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: cmn_prior.c(99): cmn_prior_update: from <
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 39.70
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -14.30
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 8.83
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -8.17
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 2.15
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -3.39
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -0.90
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -0.78
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -4.60
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 0.54
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -1.44
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 0.31
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -3.37
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ >
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: cmn_prior.c(116): cmn_prior_update: to   <
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 38.87
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -14.02
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 8.64
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -8.52
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 1.71
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -3.70
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -0.93
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -0.50
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -3.72
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 1.22
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -1.26
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 0.64
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -3.02
    04-02 22:33:11.546  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ >
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: cmn_prior.c(99): cmn_prior_update: from <
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 38.87
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -14.02
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 8.64
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -8.52
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 1.71
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -3.70
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -0.93
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -0.50
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -3.72
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 1.22
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -1.26
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 0.64
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -3.02
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ >
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: cmn_prior.c(116): cmn_prior_update: to   <
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 38.05
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -15.01
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 7.49
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -9.09
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 1.16
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -4.37
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 0.37
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 0.04
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -3.12
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 1.75
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -1.26
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ 1.58
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ -1.69
    04-02 22:33:14.549  11737-12287/rb.gui.cmusphinx_proto I/cmusphinx﹕ >
```

Comment: There is no sleep mode or anything. You can probably show your code otherwise it is hard to guess what is going on there.

Comment: UI gets blocked because your application uses too much memory most likely. It is also better to show logcat output.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev thx, updated my question with logcat output

Comment: You need to show your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the log your problem is that your try to decode too big utterance at once. The decoding takes time and blocks the UI.

For continuous listening pocketsphinx has keyword activation mode demonstrated in the demo. It is not recommended to use language model mode for continuous decoding, it is not supposed to work like that. You might listen continuous with keyword spotting mode and switch to language model for a single request.

If you still prefer language model for continuous transcription, make sure you are using more narrow beams for faster decoding and that you finalize utterances on every silence in `onEndOfSpeech` callback.

Comment: sry for this late reply, time moved fast. thank you much for this very informative answer. I'm going to try it with a thinner dictionary soon, We had a well accuracy with lm models.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not particularly familiar with PocketSphinx but have had to do the opposite with other speech recognition systems. Regardless of whether it's natively implemented or not one could add it relatively simply using a countdown timer and the listener.

OnSpeechEnd (possibly detected with a SpeechEndSignal http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/doc/sphinx4/edu/cmu/sphinx/frontend/endpoint/SpeechEndSignal.html) 
we start the countdown timer 
(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)
 with a speechRecognizer.stop() in the onFinish().
When we hear speech we cancel the timer but because the timer is linked to the SpeechEndSignal it will restart next time we stop talking. The only supplemetary step is to add a GUI element to restart the speechrecognizer given that it will be stopped at this point.

Hope that helps somewhat.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer and your expierences, and thats nearly exactly what I already do, I'm starting an timeout timer on onResult that stops and starts listenting.